# Facebook video url under https

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way of getting the facebook video thumbnail under https?

By calling 
FB.api('/me/videos/uploaded?access_token=...')

it returns me the object param "picture" with "http://vthumb.ak.fbcdn.net/hvthumb-ak-prn1/109...". When replacing "http" with "https" it shows a self-signed certificate, not showing the picture at all. Is there a way to get the thumbanils under a valid https?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the parameter `return_ssl_resources=1` to your API call, [as described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/#ssl).